# What exactly the ROC curve can tell us or can be inferred?

Tags: matlab, roc

I wrote some codes to run a linear discriminant analysis based classification:

```
%% Construct a LDA classifier with selected features and ground truth information
LDAClassifierObject                     = ClassificationDiscriminant.fit(featureSelcted, groundTruthGroup, 'DiscrimType', 'linear');
LDAClassifierResubError                 = resubLoss(LDAClassifierObject);
```

Thus, I can get

```
Resubstitution Error of LDA (Training Error): 1.7391e-01
Resubstitution Accuracy of LDA: 82.61%
Confusion Matrix of LDA:
    14     3
     1     5
```

Then I run a ROC analysis for the LDA classifier:

```
% Predict resubstitution response of LDA classifier
[LDALabel, LDAScore]                    = resubPredict(LDAClassifierObject);

% Fit probabilities for scores (the groundTruthGroup contains lables either 'Good' or 'Bad')
[FPR, TPR, Thr, AUC, OPTROCPT]      = perfcurve(groundTruthGroup(:,1), LDAScore(:,1), 'Good');
```

I have got:

```
OPTROCPT =

    0.1250    0.8667
```

Therefore, we can get:

```
Accuracy of LDA after ROC analysis: 86.91%
Confusion Matrix of LDA after ROC analysis:
    13     1
     2     7
```

My questions are:

1. After ROC analysis we obtained a better accuracy, when we report the accuracy of the classifier, which value we should use? What exactly the ROC curve can tell us or can be inferred? Can we say after ROC analysis we found a better accuracy of the LDA classifier?
2. Why the ROC can produce a better accuracy for the classifier, but the original ClassificationDiscriminant.fit can't?
3. I have also done a cross validation for the LDA classifier, like

   cvLDAClassifier                     = crossval(LDAClassifierObject, 'leaveout', 'on');

Then how to get the ROC analysis for the cross validation? '`resubPredict`' method seems only accept 'discriminant object' as input, then how can we get the scores?

4.. `classperf` function of Matlab is very handy to gather all the information of the classifier, like

```
%% Get the performance of the classifier
LDAClassifierPerformace                 = classperf(groundTruthGroup, resubPredict(LDAClassifierObject));
```

However, anyone knows how to gather these information such as accuracy, FPR, etc. for the cross validation results?

Thanks very much. I am really looking forward to see the reply to above questions.

A.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but this doesn't seem like a programming question...

Comment: Hi Eitan I think you are right, this is not totally a programming problem. First of all, I couldn't find the exactly explanation of ROC in Matlab help file, and not sure how to use it to improve the classification rate (this part isn't a programming problem). Just wondering if anyone knows something about this; however, the second part, how to coding something to get the performance of the cross validation is a programming issue. I couldn't find a handy build-in function to do these: 1. ROC of cross validation (CV); 2. Summary of the classifier performance. More interested in CV than training.

Comment: this belongs at http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't know the exact framework you're using, but ROC is a curve that allows you to see the evolution of true positives / false positive with respect to a threshold parameter (which defines how your model is "sensitive" to new samples). Indeed, ROC can help you spot the perfect value (if any) of this threshold to get the most true positives with the least false positives rate, potentially enhancing the accuracy.